# How to add multiple value to a range of date

Tags: mysql, addition, record

I have a hotel rate system which I need to record multiple values (costs) according to its room type each day. Furthermore, each set of cost depends on its agency. Every single agency has its own price rate. For example,

> Agency A has room Type A=1000, Type B=2000, Type C=3000 from 1 Dec
>   2012 - 20 Dec 2012
>   Agency B has room Type A=1200, Type B=2200, Type C=3200 from 1 Dec
>   2012 - 20 Dec 2012

Also in the future the room type maybe increase or decrease.

> Agency A has room Type A=1000, Type B=2000, Type C=3000 from 1 Dec
>   2012 - 20 Dec 2012
>   Agency C has room Type A=1200, Type B=2200, Type C=3200, Type D=3500, Type E=3700 from 1 Dec
>   2012 - 20 Dec 2012

So I have a HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
Agency : 
<select name="agency">
<option value="a">Agency A</option>
<option value="b">Agency B</option>
<option value="c">Agency C</option>
</select>

From : <input type="text" name="date1" />
To : <input type="text" name="date2" />
<?
$sql_roomType="select * from roomtype_db order by id asc";
...
while($rec_roomType=mysql_fetch_array($result_roomType)){
$_roomTypeID=$rec_roomType['id'];
$_roomTypeCost=$rec_roomType['cost'];
$_roomTypeName=$rec_roomType['name'];
echo "$_roomTypeName : <input type=\text\" name=\"cost\" /><br />";//display stack of input
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />    
</form>
```

**submit.php**

```
<?
$_agency=$_POST['agency'];
$_date1=$_POST['date1'];
$_date2=$_POST['date2'];
$_cost=$_POST['cost'];
$sql_addRate="insert into rate_db values('','$_agency','$_cost','$_date1','$_date2'";
$result_addRate=mysql_query($sql_addRate);    
?>
```

Now the problem is I'm not sure if there'll be any problem might happen in the future according to these kinda mysql method. For example, a rate can be change in a future date. A room type maybe add or delete. etc. So could you guy please show me a working script of inserting record to mySQL with normalized table.

Comment: this is kind of a huge and non-specific question. You're asking someone to design and implement the entire thing.

Comment: @GavinTowey, please read my text carefully. I'm just only requesting for "a working script of inserting record". If you don't have guts to answer I understand. And I think my question is clear and specific enough. Otherwise there's no one answer it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can achieve it in one table (where the column fields should be `id`, `agency`, `room_type`, `rate`, `start_date` and `end_date`), for a nice normalized structure you should have three tables, one for `agency`, another for `room_type` and lastly for `rates`. By moving `room_type`s to a new table it becomes easier to handle addition of further room types.

`agency` table can have fields `id` and `name` etc. `room_type` will have `id`, `name` etc again. And the `rates` will have fields `id`, `agency_id`, `room_type_id`, `rate`, `start_date` and `end_date`.

You can `SELECT` all the required fields using two inner joins. The catch is when you're trying to `INSERT` into these tables where you have a new room_type and agency to be incorporated. In such cases you will have to do three individual inserts, but still is a better design overall.

Note: I think you're missing room_type (id or name) in your insert.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. My previous version of doing such inserting. I imploded all the cost into array 
    `$cost=implode(",",$cost)` so the inserted value is like $cost='1000,2000,3000', but the problem is when I querying a cost and edit it. I have to do more lines : read, show, edit, compare then update. So this is why I'm asking for another better idea to save my time. Thanks

Comment: @Wilf I feel you are asking more a design of application question than design of db(to which I replied). I do not know php

Comment: Ah.. I just try to find the best way of making my app. Thanks